# Плавное появление кнопки

Tags: jquery, javascript

Как на JS реализовать плавное появление кнопки при наведении и плавное исчезновение? Можно на jQuery.

Comment: Изменяйте прозрачность кнопки функцией animation() в jQ и всё.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так (jQuery ):

```
$("#something").hover(function () {
    // Устанавливает прозрачность в 1 при наведении
    $("#something").fadeTo("slow", 1.0);
}, function () {
     // Устанавливает прозрачность в 0 при выведении
    $("#something").fadeTo("slow", 0.0);
});
```